# inject_dll_x86.exe is detected like malware #9474

Tags: pydev

I just installed latest `PyDev` on `Eclipse` on Windows and run into issue:

> inject_dll_x86.exe is detected like malware #9474.

When will the fix of signing the dll be included in the Windows release?

```
Eclipse 
Windows 10
Python 3.8.2
PyDev 7.5
McAfee 10.6.1
```

> Error: xxx ran C:\eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe, which attempted to access xxx.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.5.0.202001101138\pysrc\pydevd_attach_to_process\inject_dll_x86.exe. The Trojan named Artemis!26A732476DE5 was detected and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Got the similar message from "360 Total Security" after istalled PyDev on Eclipse for Java developers.

HEUR/QVM10.1.169D.Malware.Gen

File has been deleted.

Should I restore it and add to white list?